# Invalid Syntax in nested IIf statement of Access query- "You may have entered a comma without a preceding value or identifier"

Tags: ms-access

For the life of me I cannot figure out what I am missing.  My eyes are going crossed and I am sure it is very simple.  Can anyone help my sanity?

I am trying to assign a severity if the value is within certain ranges.

Here is what I am trying:

```
Severity: IIf(([CVSS]<4), "Low", IIf(([CVSS]>=9), "Critical", IIf(([CVSS]>4 AND <6.9), "Medium", "High")))
```

The full error is:

> The expression you entered contains invalid syntax.
>   You may have entered a comma without a preceding value or identifier.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must repeat field name in AND clause (`CVSS>4 AND CVSS<6.9`). Expression will return High if CVSS is null. Expression doesn't return a value for exactly 4.

Consider:

`Severity: IIf([CVSS]<=4, "Low",  IIf([CVSS]<=6.9, "Medium", IIf([CVSS]<=9, "High", IIf([CVSS]>9,"Critical", Null))))`

Or:

`Severity: Switch([CVSS]<=4, "Low", [CVSS]<=6.9, "Medium", [CVSS]<=9, "High", [CVSS]>9, "Critical")`

Comment: Beautiful, thank you.  I like the Switch function, I didn't know about so thank you for the education!

Comment: If answer resolved issue, could mark it as accepted. Another function you might explore is Choose().